# WKWebView Add to SubView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview

I can add a WKWebView programmatically to a subview with the code below. How can I add WKWebView to the view containerView2 that was added via Interface Builder?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var containerView2: UIView!

var webView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {

    super.loadView()

    self.webView = WKWebView()

    self.webView?.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)
    self.webView?.sizeToFit()
    self.containerView = self.webView!
    //how can I set a View (containerView2) added by Interface Builder =  to self.webView!

    self.view.addSubview(self.containerView!)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com")
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If `containerView2` is created via Interface Builder and `containerView` is basically your `WKWebView` `loadView()` method might look like:

```
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        webView = WKWebView()
        containerView = self.webView!

        containerView.frame = containerView2.frame
        containerView2.addSubview(containerView)
    }
```

And of course you can have better names for your views. For example, the "parent" element could be called `containerView` and your `WKWebView` could just be called `webView`. In this way code becomes much more readable:

```
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        webView = WKWebView()

        if (webView != nil) {
            webView!.frame = containerView.frame
            containerView.addSubview(webView!)
        }
    }
```