# Migrate UIWebView to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Within my iOS app I am attempting to migrate my old UIWebView code to WKWebView since WKWebView is, in theory, faster and more efficient than UIWebView.

I have looked at a bunch of tutorials (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665141/migrate-to-wkwebview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665141/migrate-to-wkwebview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027100/wkwebview-add-to-subview)) on the internet but cant find anything that explains how to simply add a WKWebView to my app progmatically.

Can someone point me to a simple tutorial or explain in the comments how to convert this code to WKWebView progmatically? thanks in advance.

View Controller.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.communionchapelefca.org/app-home")!))
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
```

Comment: Change the places that say `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add "**WebKit**" framework to your class.

Please refer  the below code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,   UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.communionchapelefca.org/app-home")!))
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

    }
}
```

Comment: that worked; thanks! I feel like an idiot that it was so simple to change/adjust to WKWebView.

Comment: @GregWilliams http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Just a note: needs use `NSAppTransportSecurity` with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in `info.plist` to works.

Comment: @CarlosIrano That's only needed whilst using an HTTP url - and if that specific url is all that is needed, it can be whitelisted instead of enabling `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` `;)`

Comment: FYI myWebView.loadRequest is now replaced with myWebView.load