# Display Auth Prompt in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sharepoint, office365

I would like to access to a Sharepoint site, but the UIWebView is blocked when Office365 try redirect me to my auth organization page. On desktop, I see a prompt with 2 text fields, but, nothing here! Here is my code, and a screenshot:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var refresh: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let theURL = URL(string: "https://expertime365.sharepoint.com/sites/retail-portal-v8/Pages/default.aspx") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: theURL)

        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You need to migrate UIWebView to WkWebView. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214247/migrate-uiwebview-to-wkwebview

Comment: That's ok, I'm not blocked, BUT, prompt doesn't appear. 401 error page :s

Answer (score 0):

Have did check url which are load in your webView ?

if you not then check following link and compare with that url which are loaded in Desktop browser.

You can check with below code :

```
func webView(webview: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    let currentURL = request.URL.absoluteString
    print("\(currentURL)")
  }
```