# WKWebView add as a subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, wkwebview

From iOS 8.0+, I am supposed to use `WKWebView`, but in the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview), they add it by setting the view as the WKWebView. I need to add it as a subview, for numerous reasons.

1. I have to add buttons/labels above the `WKWebView`.
2. I can add it by adding a `UIView` to the storyboard and then setting it by code to `WKWebView`, which looks neater then adding it by code.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

private var wkWebView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfig)
    wkWebView.uiDelegate = self
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    container = wkWebView

    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    wkWebView.load(request)
}
```

I have tried this: [WKWebView Add to SubView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027100/wkwebview-add-to-subview)

I have also tried the `container.addSubview` method, which crashed with a nil pointer.

Every time I load up the app, there's just a black screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried   Container view controllers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just add the instance of `WKWebView` as a subview to a given view:

```
view.addSubview(wkWebView)
```

You can set its frame, add constraints to it etc., just like you would with a `UIView`.

Comment: It's weird apple forces you to use there WKWebView from newer versions but they don't add it in to the storyboard...

Comment: @SamuelKodytek Strange indeed, I agree. However, this is an easy (and quite the only) method to do the same thing from code.